# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, button and tabs

Tags: javascript, properties, styles, undefined

I want to show a tab, when clicking on the associated button. But I get that error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at openTab (script.js:8)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:21)"

So, if you click on one button in the menu on the left, the function openTab should open the associated tab.

```js
function openTab (event, tabName){
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    
    // get all elements with class = 'tabcontent' and hide them    
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
    for (i = 0; tabcontent.length; i++){
        tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // get all elements with class = 'tablinks' and remove the class 'active'
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
    for (i =0; tablinks.length;i++){
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace('active', '');
    }

    //show the current tab, and add an 'active' class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
    evt.currentTarget.className += 'active';

}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    text-align: center;
}

#webseite{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1500px;

}

#header {
    height: 150;
    background-color: wheat;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#header h1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

#menue {
    float: left;
    width:20% ;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: wheat;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#inhalt{
    float: left;
    width: 78.65%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: wheat;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.tablinks{
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: wheat;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.tablinks:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tabcontent{
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;

}

.tabcontent tab_tabelle_vorspeisen{
    display: block;
    background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Rezepteverwaltung</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="webseite">

            <div id="header">
                <h1>Rezepte</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="main">


                <div id="menue">
                    <table class="tabelle_menue">
                        <button onclick="openTab(event,'tab_tabelle_vorspeisen')" class="tablinks" >Vorspeisen</button>
                        <button onclick="openTab(event,'tab_tabelle_hauptspeisen')" class="tablinks">Hauptgerichte</button>
                        <button onclick="openTab(event,'tab_tabelle_nachspeisen')" class="tablinks" >Nachspeise</button>
                        <button onclick="openTab(event,'tab_tabelle_suppen')" class="tablinks" >Suppen</button>

                    </table>
                </div>


                <div id="inhalt">

                    <div class="tabcontent" id='tab_tabelle_vorspeisen' >
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>
                        <div>Vorspeise</div>


                    </div>
                                
                    <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_tabelle_hauptspeisen" >
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>
                        <div>Hauptspeise</div>


                    </div>
                
                    <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_tabelle_nachspeisen" >
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>
                        <div>Nachspeisen</div>



                    </div>

                    <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_tabelle_suppen" >
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>
                        <div>Suppe</div>



                    </div>
                
                
                
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These for loops needs limitation for sure. i mean:

```
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++){
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Also do the same changes for other loop. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change
1.
 `for (i = 0; tabcontent.length; i++)`
to
 `for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++)`
2.
  `(i =0; tablinks.length;i++)`
to
  `for (i =0; i < tablinks.length; i++)`
3.
`evt.currentTarget.className += 'active';`
to
`event.currentTarget.className += 'active';`

P.S Tip, see how it is implemented in some popular framework, for example bootstrap ('tabs')